# how to made image in class="row" in bootstrap be in the middle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a problem with my website: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKf3U.png).

How do I make what I circled be in the middle, parallel with the navbar?
This is my code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="" alt="">
<div class="caption">
<h4>label</h4>
<p>adadasdasd</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">add to chart</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, maybe you can read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

With the grid basic, you know col-12 is the whole width.
If you want to make it in the middle try this:
(This might not be the best code here, but should work).

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <YOUR BOX GO HERE>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

Let me know if it was helpful.

Thanks

Comment: yaya 2nd post in overflow and already a good answer ;D ! Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the `.col-md-offset-*` class. So in your case when it has a width of 4 units, offset it 4 units with `col-md-offset-4` so that it will have 4 units on each side and be centered.

Comment: I'm not understanding what didn't work. You want the circled box to be centered, no? Can you post a jsfiddle with your code so I can better understand how to answer your question?